# Node had taints that the pod didn't tolerate error when deploying to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy my microservices into Kubernetes cluster. My cluster having one master and one worker node. I created this cluster for my R&D of Kubernetes deployment. When I am trying to deploy I am getting the even error message like the following,

```
Events:
 Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
 Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate
```

**My attempt**

When I am exploring about the error, I found some comments in forums for restarting the docker in the node etc. So after that I restarted Docker. But still the error is the same.

When I tried the command `kubectl get nodes` it showing like that both nodes are master and both are `ready` state.

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
 mildevkub020   Ready    master   6d19h   v1.17.0
 mildevkub040   Ready    master   6d19h   v1.17.0
```

I did not found worker node here. I created one master (mildevkub020) and one worker node (mildev040) with one load balancer. And I followed the official documentation of Kubernetes from the following link,

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

**My question**

Is this error is because of the cluster problem? Because I am not finding the cluster worker node. Only master node.

Comment: The answer has been given to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59491824/6064025

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can run below command to remove the taint from master node and then you should be able to deploy your pod on that node

```
kubectl taint nodes  mildevkub020 node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
kubectl taint nodes  mildevkub040 node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Now regarding why its showing as master node check the command you ran to join the node with kubeadm. There are separate commands for master and worker node joining.

Comment: Thanks! To remove taint from **all** master nodes: `for node in $(kubectl get nodes --selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/master' | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' ) ; do
  kubectl taint node $node node-role.kubernetes.io/master- ;
done`

Comment: when i dod that i get `error: taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" not found`

Comment: To add some info to the answer, use `kubectl describe nodes` to see the taints of the nodes, the name you give in the command above should exactly match the taint that you are trying to remove. Also important, the `-` at the end of the provided command is what tells kubectl to remove the taint.

Answer (score 14):

You can also get this "taint" type of message when your docker environment doesn't have enough resources allocated.

For example, in Docker Desktop for Mac, allocate more memory/cpu/swap in preferences, and it may solve your problem.

This can also happen if kubernetes auto scaling doesn't have enough nodes to launch a new pod, which you will may see as "Insufficient CPU" on describe.

Comment: Had this same "taint" events when configuring ingress-nginx for mac for the first time. The ingress controller got stuck in Pending state. Doubling up memory and swap allocation solved it.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the taints on the master so that you can schedule pods on it.

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

It should return the following.

```
node/<your-hostname> untainted
```

Answer (score 5):

In k8s version 1.24.2, you have to run below command:

```
kubectl taint nodes <node_name> dedicated=special-user:NoSchedule
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The same issue I had faced because my Kubernetes worker node was down(turned off)

```
Manjunath-MacBook-Air:manjunath$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                       STATUS     ROLES   AGE   VERSION
aks-agentpool-****-*   NotReady   agent   31d   v1.18.10
```

After starting the VM(Kubernetes worker instance ), the issue got resolved

```
Manjunath-MacBook-Air: manjunath$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                       STATUS   ROLES   AGE   VERSION
aks-agentpool-****-*   Ready    agent   31d   v1.18.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I get this with microk8s when I reboot the machine that my "cluster" runs on.  Enough of microk8s comes back online to convince me that it's "up", but pods get stuck pending with this error.

I just have to run `microk8s start` and whatever is stuck gets unstuck (until the next reboot).

Answer (score 2):

Put the name of the node that gives us this error : FailedScheduling

```
kubectl taint nodes <name-node-master> node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-
```

example :

```
kubectl taint nodes prod-k8s-master.octopeek-dns.com node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes 1.24+ you need to run this command to allow scheduling apps on the master/control-plane nodes:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane- node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#control-plane-node-isolation

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on Kubernetes **1.26.x** :

```bash
kubectl taint nodes mildevkub020 node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-
```

Answer (score 1):

For Kubernetes version v1.25.5, in my case I've added the following tolerations to my deployments

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: <image_name>
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
      tolerations:
        - key: <node_key> # IMPORTANT here
          operator: Equal
          value: "true"
          effect: NoSchedule
```

To get nodes taint keys, use the following command:

```
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{.spec.taints}{"\n\n"}{end}'
```

Update `key`, `operator`, `value`, `effect` to meet with node taints.

Comment: This worked for me! all I needed to get is the key for the tolerations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in docs.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/running-cloud-controller/

> Keep in mind that setting up your cluster to use cloud controller
> manager will change your cluster behaviour in a few ways:
>
> kubelets specifying --cloud-provider=external will add a taint
> node.cloudprovider.kubernetes.io/uninitialized with an effect
> NoSchedule during initialization. This marks the node as needing a
> second initialization from an external controller before it can be
> scheduled work. Note that in the event that cloud controller manager
> is not available, new nodes in the cluster will be left unschedulable.
> The taint is important since the scheduler may require cloud specific
> information about nodes such as their region or type (high cpu, gpu,
> high memory, spot instance, etc).

Answer (score 0):

these commands work with all nodes
for control-plane

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-
```

for master

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue a while ago and had to add tolerations to overcome this.

```
tolerations:
  - key: "os"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "windows"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```