# Taint eks node-group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a cluster with 2 node groups: *real time* and *general*. I would like only pods which tolerate affinity *real time* to be able to run on nodes from the *real time* cluster.
My approach was to *taint* the relevant nodes and add *toleration* to the pod that I want to register to that node. I came into a dead-end when I was trying to taint a node-group. In my case I have an EKS node group that is elastic, i.e. nodes are increasing and decreasing in numbers constantly. How can I configure the group so that nodes from one group will be tainted upon creation?

Comment: I wish my answer can help you to taint the nodes https://stackoverflow.com/a/59491824/6064025

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494867/how-to-add-taint-to-aws-eks-node-group/72459934#72459934

Answer (score 7):

I assume you're creating your nodeGroup via CloudFormation?

If that is the case you can add `--kubelet-extra-args --register-with-taints={key}={value}:NoSchedule` as your ${BootstrapArguments} for your LaunchConfig

`/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${clusterName} ${BootstrapArguments}`

That way, whenever you scale up or down your cluster, a Node will be spawned with the appropriate taint.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this on k8s' controller level? On new node taint if has certain tag?

Comment: I highly doubt it, If I were to do your setup, I would create 2 different scale groups with their own Launch config. One for General, One for Real Time

Comment: Will this work for an AWS managed node group? For AMI updates AWS will create a new template version and I assume that the LaunchConfig for the new version will not be derived from the modified older version but from an AWS internal template, thus overwriting the modification.