# How to add taint to AWS EKS node Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, azure-aks

I am having one AWS EKS Cluster up & running. I need to add node group with taint. So that I can deploy the pod on particular node group in EKS. I can do it in azure AKS using the following command.

```bash
az aks nodepool add --resource-group rg-xx --cluster-name aks-xxx --name np1 --node-count 1 --node-vm-size xxx --node-taints key=value:NoSchedule --no-wait
```

How to achieve same in AWS EKS?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this example: https://eksctl.io/usage/autoscaling/#scaling-up-from-0

```
nodeGroups:
- name: ng1-public
  ...
  labels:
    my-cool-label: pizza
  taints:
    feaster: "true:NoSchedule"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I don't want to used eksctl .. Is there any other way to do it such as from UI or AWS CLI command ?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using eksctl with managed nodegroups, you can patch the bootstrap script to achieve what you want.

```
managedNodeGroups:
  - name: batch
    preBootstrapCommands:
      - sed -i '/^KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=/a KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS+=" --register-with-taints=tier=batch:NoSchedule"' /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh
    tags:
      k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/node-template/taint/tier: "batch:NoSchedule"
```

this relies on the code at https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/189baaa77c14120a1b62c42bacced17ba429466b/files/bootstrap.sh#L107 not changing too much.

You can similarly enable the docker network bridge (aka `--enable-docker-bridge`)

```
    preBootstrapCommands:
      - sed -i 's/^ENABLE_DOCKER_BRIDGE=.*/ENABLE_DOCKER_BRIDGE=true/' bootstrap.sh
```

The tracking issue for actual EKS support is at https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/864, and this solution comes from a comment

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes taints are supported by EKS managed NodeGroups since April 2021: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/node-taints-managed-node-groups.html

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for a solution **Using eksctl + yaml file**

You can run the following command

```
eksctl create nodegroup --config-file=<clusterconfig.yaml>
```

`<clusterconfig.yaml>` is the file that you used to create your cluster. (Yes you can use the same file to create a new nodegroup/managednodegroup.) Add the new new managednodegroup and run the create command. `eksctl` will take a diff and create the new nodegroup. My cluster config looks like the yaml I have pasted below. I created nodegroup `ng-system` during the creation of the cluster. I later added a new cluster group `ng-kafka`, with taints, through the command I mentioned above.

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: test-cluster
  region: us-east-2
  version: "1.22"
managedNodeGroups:
  - name: ng-system
    instanceType: t3.medium
    minSize: 3
    maxSize: 10
    spot: true
    maxPodsPerNode: 35
    labels: {
      role: system
    }
  - name: ng-kafka
    instanceType: m5.large
    desiredCapacity: 2
    minSize: 1
    maxSize: 4
    spot: true
    taints:
      - {
          "key": "dedicated",
          "value": "kafka",
          "effect": "NoSchedule"
        }
    ssh:
      allow: true
    labels: {
      role: kafka
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen *eksctl* as a requirment in the question so I'm adding another 2 options.

##### Option 1 - AWS CLI

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/node-taints-managed-node-groups.html):

> Kubernetes node taints can be applied to new and existing managed node
> groups using the AWS Management Console or through the Amazon EKS API

The following is an example of creating a node group with a taint using the AWS CLI:

```
aws eks create-nodegroup \
 --cli-input-json '
{
  "clusterName": "my-cluster",
  ...
  "taints": [
     {
         "key": "dedicated",
         "value": "gpuGroup",
         "effect": "NO_SCHEDULE"
     }
   ],
}'
```

##### Option 2 - Terraform

If you're using *Terraform* then [Hashicorp AWS provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs) supports taints out of the box with the [taint configuration block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#taint):

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "stateless-ng" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.main.name
  node_group_name = "stateless-ng"
  .
  .
  .
  
  # Block 1 
  taint {
    key = "stateless-no-schedule"
    value  = "true"
    effect = "NO_SCHEDULE"
  }

  # Block 2    
  taint {
    key = "stateless-no-execute"
    value  = "true"
    effect = "NO_EXECUTE"
  }
}
```

Notice that each taint needs to be configured in a sperated configuration block.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add like this in AWS:EKS:NodeGroup Cloudformation Template

```
Taints:
  - Effect: "NO_SCHEDULE"
    Key: !Ref NodeGroupName
    Value: "dedicated"
```